# Is there a jQuery event that fires when all effects are done running

Tags: jquery

The title explains the question, otherwise is there way to call a function when all the effects on a page are done running?

Comment: How are you calling these effects? There may be other ways to execute a function once they are done.

Comment: I mean, are the effects all called within the same function and in response to the same event? Can you post a tiny example?

Answer (score 3):

You could nest your animations like this

```
$('#Div1').slideDown('fast', function(){
   $('#Div2').slideUp('fast');
});
```

And do them sequentially...

You could also do something like this:

```
var animations = 0;
checkAnimation(1);
$('#Div1').slideDown('fast', function(){
   checkAnimation(-1);
});

checkAnimation(count){
   animations += count;
   if(count == 0)
      //animations complete
   }
   else {
       //still animating
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to make use of **.queue** to get the functionality you are after.  If the length of the queue was 0 you would know that all animations on the object are finished.

[Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/queue)

Comment: that is close, though I was hoping for a way to do this without changing the existing effects.

Comment: I haven't seen your code, but my understanding is that the queue gets populated for any object running an animation.  I don't expect there would be big changes to your code in order to query the queue array.